# Xamarin :: Android - Original attribute defined here

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin Android Project with Target Framework v9.

[image]

Recently, I updated my Xamarin Forms to latest version. Then, I am getting below error.

[image]

I understand from the error message that I need to update 'Target Framework' from Android 9 to Android 10. I did it.

[image]

From that moment, whenever I build my android project in 'Release' mode, I get below error. Building project in 'Debug' mode is fine.

[image]

May you please help? I need to submit an update to my Android App. :-(

Comment: Did you enable the **Use incremental Android packaging system (Aapt2)**? Someone faced the similar issue and solve it by enable this function. Please enable the option and test again.

Similar cases:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/7
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/172279/error-apt1000-attribute-34imageaspectratioadjust34.html

If it doesn't work, try to empry the bin and obj folders to clean up the solution for test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment of "Lucas Zhang - MSFT":

Please enable the

> Use incremental Android packaging system (Aapt2)

which is available under Project Properties. It will resolve the error you posted.